# Pandas - Edit a single dataframe value from a returned subset based on condition WITHOUT a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, subset

As the title says consider the following for loop example below. 'df' is a dataframe with several rows and several columns:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  if row[3] == condition_a and row[4] == condition_b:
    df.at[index, 0] = value_1
    df.at[index, 1] = value_2
    break
```

This works fine and does the job. (I know you are not supposed to edit a dataFrame inside a loop...) However I am wondering can I do this better as this entire loop is inside a parent loop already.

The issue is that **I only want the very first ROW of the returned subset to be edited** and NOT the entire subset. That's why the "break" inside the loop.

I've tried to do the following:

```
df.loc[(df[3] == condition_a) & (df[4] == condition_b), 0].iloc[0] = value_1
# plus another line to change pos 1 to value_2
```

While this doesn't cause any errors it also doesn't assign anything (changes nothing in df). I was hoping to avoid creating a new temporary dataFrame to edit values and then merge back with the original df. Wouldn't that be slower than the loop?

So question is: Can this be done or is the loop the only solution here? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I'm not expert here but wouldn't just `df.loc[(df[3] == condition_a) & (df[4] == condition_b), 0] = value_1` work?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately not for what I want. This will edit the entire returned subset but I only want the first row of the returned subset to be edited.

Comment: Ah! OK. Now I understand why iloc is in play here. Sorry I misunderstood that.

Comment: All good. Thanks for looking at it either way. Appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the minimal index where the conditions are met and use it to set the new values:

```
ix = df[(df.iloc[:,3] == condition_a)&(df.iloc[:,4]==condition_b)].index.min()
df.loc[ix, df.columns[[0, 1]]] = [value_1, value_2]
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for that. Seems suddenly very obvious to use index but couldn't think of that. Thanks a mill for answering this so fast. Much appreciated!

PS: Minor edit for two missing brackets:
```df.loc[ix, df.columns[[0, 1]]] = [value_1, value_2]```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer from @Serge Ballesta is sufficient, but only if the index is sorted.

If this is not the case, I would suggest

```py
condition = (df.loc[:,3] == condition_a) & (df.loc[:,4] == condition_b)
ix = df[condition].index[0]
df.loc[ix, 0] = value_1
df.loc[ix, 1] = value_2
```

Also maybe use strings instead of integers for your column names, to avoid confusion with indexes

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This also works well. And yeah I was too lazy to name them :D
Cheers